# Geogebra for Blind People

Tags: geometry, technology-in-education, special-needs-education

I work in the University with students in a situation of disability, specifically, teaching them math and related things. I have a few students that are very visually impaired; they work with JAWS or NVDA, usually.

When we are working in Calculus or some course which depends a bit in visual things to be understood, it goes slow.

I'd like that the dynamics of the teaching were more fluid. So, I'm searching for some way to teach [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en), so they can apply these things for their study. Sadly, I think that Geogebra isn't too accessible for the visually impaired

I wonder if anyone have some good ideas to do a good geometric work with some accessible software, or if you know somehow to work with Geogebra for this purpose.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Geogebra has a powerful command line that can (probably) do everything you could do using a mouse. What features of Geogebra are you looking for in particular?

Comment: GeoGebra has lots of support for screenreader and keyboard-only use - send us an email if you need something adding support@geogebra.org

Answer (score 6):

Desmos Geometry is not as fully featured as GeoGebra. However, Desmos does have specific features for the visually impaired such a screen reader support, braille support, and audio trace. These features may not currently work for the [www.desmos.com/geometry](http://www.desmos.com/geometry) section, but perhaps the [www.desmos.com/calculator](http://www.desmos.com/calculator) fits some of your needs.

See more details and instructions here: https://www.desmos.com/accessibility